# SysLink focus rectangle

Tags: windows, winapi

Does anyone know how to remove the focus rectangle on this item? I have used successfully the WM_UPDATEUISTATE message with buttons but it has no noticeable effect on syslinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess and say that because SysLink controls have a definite focused state (`LIS_FOCUSED`), they ignore the UI state flag which would otherwise make them suppress the focus rectangle.

If this is the case then I'd say you could use the `LM_SETITEM` message with `LF_STATE` to remove the `LIS_FOCUSED` state from the control. You would probably need to sub-class the control and do this immediately after it processes the `WM_SETFOCUS` message, although the control may set this state after other messages too so some experimentation would be required.